# How to avoid losing your viminfo (command history, and so on) on abort?

Tags: sessions

Your command history, marks, etc are lost when exiting on seg fault / forcingly closing gui app(i.e. `cmd-Q` on mac) .

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to answer this question in neovim.

They support shada files which store your chosen info between sessions.
You can choose what information is kept.  See `:help shada`.

You just need to set timer and call `wshada` to update the file every several seconds.

```
function! TimerFunc(a)
    :wshada
endfunction

let g:autosaveWS=timer_start(10000,'TimerFunc',{'repeat':-1})
```

Comment: Vim has [`:wviminfo`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#%3Awviminfo) which looks analogous...